# Nativescript | text direction ltr

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm having a ui problem with devices that their language direction is right to left. 
how can i override this setting and make sure that in my app it will always have direction left to right.

i'v tried to use css.

```
body{
  text-diraction:rtl
}
```

But it didnt work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `body` in NativeScript. The HTML you can set within an Angular Project is just a markup that will be used to create Native elements. You have to use only the selector provided by NativeScript (or plugins).

For this reason, any CSS/HTML property has to be supported by NativeScript to work, otherwise it won't have any effect. For more information, take a look at the [support css properties in the documentation.](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/styling#supported-css-properties)

Second, you made a mistake in the word `text-direction` so even in HTML/CSS it won't work.

Third, the LTR/RTL support is provided by the native platform (iOS/Android), not by the framework. Using GridLayout, your phone will do the flip if needed.

Here is a project that use a RTL language: [SyrianForumFrance](https://github.com/rkhayyat/SyrianForumFrance)

You can find more info on this thread of the NativeScript forum: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/nativescript-support-for-rtl-ltr-layouts/3952

Comment: `GridLayout` does not flip in RTL languages. Currently you need to create a new `xml` file to support `RTL`. You can also use `FlexBoxLayout` and `row-reverse`. I hope that RTL support for `GridLayout` will be add soon. [Ref.](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/nativescript-support-for-rtl-ltr-layouts/3952)

Answer (score 0):

In order to force rtl direction of text you need to implement a loaded event of object and inside to force direction.

In html:

```
<Label text="test text" (loaded)="onLabelLoaded($event)"></Label>
```

In Angular:

```
onLabelLoaded(event)
{        
    event.object.textAlignment = "right";
}
```